# Ошибка при вызове мутации vuex из компонента vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть глобальной `store`, в котором `state = текущее состояние`, мутация  `CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU` меняет текущее состояние.
Есть компонент `NavMenu`, в котором вызываю мутацию `CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU` и передаю в качестве параметра строку (название элемента, по которому произошел клик) => получаю ошибку: `this.CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU is not a function`

В чем проблема?

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({

state: {
    currentNav: 'interior',
    showMenu: false
},
getters:  {
    NAV_LINKS: (state) => {
        let links = {
            interior: [
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/1.jpg',
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/2.jpg',
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                }
            ],
            exterior: [
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/3.jpg',
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/4.jpg',
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/5.jpg',
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
            vr: [
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/6.jpg',
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/7.jpg',
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/8.jpg',
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
            animation: [
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/9.jpg',
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/10.jpg',
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    url: './assets/img/gallery/11.jpg',
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
        }


        if (state.currentNav === 'interior') 
        return links.interior

        else return links.exterior
    }
},

mutations: {
    CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(state, value) {
       state.currentNav = value
}

}
})
```

Компонент:

```
<template>
    <div class="nav-menu">
        <ul class="accordion" v-for="(work, index) of works"
        :key="`${work}_${index}`"
        >
            <li @click="openSubmenu(index)">
              <div class="accordion__title"
              >{{work.name}}</div>
              <ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu', {'hidden' : index !== activeIndex}]">
            <li 
                class="submenu submenu__item"
                v-for="category in work.categories"
                :key="`${category}_${category}`"
                @click="getCategoriesItem(category)"
                >{{category}}
                
                </li>
                 
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
export default {
    name: 'NavMenu',
    data: () => ({
        activeIndex: null,
        category: '',
        works: [
            {name: 'archetecture', categories:  ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']},
            {name: 'not archetecture', categories:  ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']}
        ]
    }),
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['NAV_LINKS']),
    ...mapMutations(['CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU'])

    },
    methods: {
        openSubmenu(id) {
            this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === id ? null : id
        },
        getCategoriesItem(navItem) {
            this.CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(navItem)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `mapMutations(['CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU'])` в `methods` поместите - во vuex мутации это не геттеры, а методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мутации можно вызывать из кода компонентов, используя `this.$store.commit('xxx')`, или применяя **вспомогательный метод** `mapMutations`, который проксирует вызовы `store.commit` через методы компонентов (для этого требуется наличие корневой ссылки на хранилище `$store`):

[Мутации Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/mutations.html)

Рабочий пример:

```js
const {
  mapGetters,
  mapMutations
} = Vuex;

const store = new Vuex.Store({

  state: {
    currentNav: 'interior',
    showMenu: false
  },
  getters: {
    NAV_LINKS: (state) => {
      let links = {
        interior: [{
            url: './assets/img/gallery/1.jpg',
            name: 'interior',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/2.jpg',
            name: 'interior',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          }
        ],
        exterior: [{
            url: './assets/img/gallery/3.jpg',
            name: 'exterior',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/4.jpg',
            name: 'exterior',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/5.jpg',
            name: 'exterior',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },

        ],
        vr: [{
            url: './assets/img/gallery/6.jpg',
            name: 'vr',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/7.jpg',
            name: 'vr',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/8.jpg',
            name: 'vr',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },

        ],
        animation: [{
            url: './assets/img/gallery/9.jpg',
            name: 'animation',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/10.jpg',
            name: 'animation',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },
          {
            url: './assets/img/gallery/11.jpg',
            name: 'animation',
            route: {
              name: 'Gallery',
              params: {}
            },
            active: ['Company']
          },

        ],
      }


      if (state.currentNav === 'interior')
        return links.interior

      else return links.exterior
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(state, value) {
      console.clear()
      console.log('CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU', value)
      state.currentNav = value
    }

  }
})




new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: () => ({
    activeIndex: null,
    category: '',
    works: [{
        name: 'archetecture',
        categories: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']
      },
      {
        name: 'not archetecture',
        categories: ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['NAV_LINKS'])
  },
  methods: {
    openSubmenu(id) {
      this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === id ? null : id
    },
    getCategoriesItem(navItem) {
      this.CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(navItem)
    },
    ...mapMutations(['CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU']),
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="accordion" v-for="(work, index) of works" :key="`${work}_${index}`">
      <li>
        <div @click.stop="openSubmenu(index)" class="accordion__title">{{work.name}}</div>
        <ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu', {'hidden' : index !== activeIndex}]">
          <li class="submenu submenu__item" v-for="category in work.categories" :key="`${category}_${category}`" @click="getCategoriesItem(category)">{{category}}

          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```